# Exponential Fundamental Limits without using L'Hôspital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I have a limit to  evaluate.

$$\lim_{x\to2} \left(\frac{\mathrm e^x - \mathrm e^2}{x-2}\right)$$

Can someone solve it without using L'Hôspital and explain me the steps?

Thanks

Comment: It is only the definition of derivative of exponecial function evaluated in 2

Comment: One does not "solve" a limit. If a limit exists then it takes a value. For that reason, one "evaluates" a limit, or "finds the value of" a limit.

Comment: In fact, it is circular reasoning to use H's rule here: the rule basically says "use derivatives to calculate a limit" - it doesn't make sense, morally speaking, to do so when the limit to calculate is one of the derivatives.... i.e., if one uses H here, one is using the answer to find the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Do the substitution $x=t+2$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^{t+2}-e^2}{t}=e^2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}
$$
The final limit is standard: if you're not allowed to use l'Hôpital, this limit should be allowed to use.

Comment: Especially if $\exp^\prime(0)$ is known :)

Comment: @ClementC. I indeed find these exercises very silly. This is the derivative of $x\mapsto e^x$ at $2$ and asking to “compute” it is a waste of time.

Comment: @FlybyNight It's quite difficult to draw a line in these cases: it's not known what the OP is allowed to use.

Comment: This is quite a difficult limit. If I recall, you need to define 
$$\mathrm e = \lim_{r \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{r}\right)^r$$
and then use the substitution 
$$r = \frac{1}{\mathrm e^t-1}$$

Comment: @FlybyNight  You can also start by defining $\exp$ as the function with $\exp^\prime = \exp$... or as a power series, for which his is also quite immediate.

Comment: @ClementC. **IMHO** Those definitions seem a little dishonest from a historical and pedagogical point of view. They are properties of the exponential function, but the function is introduced through continuous growth/decay. One property of the exponential function is that it's an eigenfunction of the derivative, but that ought to be proved. Its power series comes from knowing its derivative. To define the exponential in terms of its power series strips it of any meaning. After all, who would serious introduce sine and cosine without mention of right-angled triangles?

Comment: Not me, but I can imagine people doing so... my point was simply to say that this question can range from trivial from involved, depending on what is assumed "basic knowledge" (which the OP didn't specify).

Comment: @FlybyNight I introduce it as the inverse of the logarithm.

Comment: @egreg and the logarithm as?

Comment: @FlybyNight Of course as the integral of $1/x$. Which is the historical pattern, essentially.

Comment: @egreg - see my comment to the original question - I think H's rule cannot be allowed here - what do you think?

Comment: @egreg By the "integral of $\frac{1}{x}$", I think you mean the *definite* integral
$$\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}~\mathrm dt$$
After all
$$\int \frac{1}{x}~\mathrm dx = \ln|x|+C$$

Comment: @FlybyNight Yes, the integral (antiderivative is a different, though related thing).

Comment: @egreg Definite Integral and Anti-derivative are synonyms.

Comment: @FlybyNight Via the fundamental theorem, which is not trivial, is it?

Comment: @egreg No, it's not trivial; but it is a fact.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the definition of "derivative": $f'(a) = \lim\limits_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Now let $f(x) = e^x$ and $a=2$.  Then you have $f'(x)=e^x$ so $f'(2) = e^2$ and so
$$
e^2 = f'(2) = \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{e^x-e^2}{x-2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

One could use the mean value theorem as well:

$$ \frac{e^{x}-e^2}{x-2} = \frac{e^{\xi(x)}(x-2)}{x-2}=e^{\xi(x)}$$

for some $\xi$ between $x$ and 2. Hence, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \xi(x)=2$ and thus

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{e^{x}-e^2}{x-2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 2} e^{\xi(x)} = e^2.$$